# distorted color of images in java swing gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have for example the following picture displayed in my gui:

http://www.zielpunkt.at/image/produkte/1354097303-airwick.jpg

Unfortunately the colors are distorted (pink background):

My code:

```
URL pictureURL = new URL(product.getBild()); 
            BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(pictureURL);
            JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridwidth = 2;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 5;
            panel.add(picLabel,c);
```

Looking forwart to your answers!
Regards,

[image: screenshot]

Most of my images look like this, but when I look at the graphic on the url it looks normal.

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Comment: Can you link to the distorted picture?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963685/java-buffered-image-created-with-red-mask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963685/java-buffered-image-created-with-red-mask)

Comment: Upgrade JDK/JRE to the latest (7+) and try again maybe its that bug linked by @whiskeyspider. Also wouldhelp to post small [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3432532/230513), the "pinkish tint" may be due to misinterpreted transparency information. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513), "one simple expedient is to render the image" into a compatible `BufferedImage`.