# How to Read JPEG image into BufferedImage object using Java

Tags: java, image, jpeg

This is not a duplicated question here, because I've been searching for the solution for a long time in Google and StackOverflow, and still cannot find a solution.

I have these two images:

[image: Larger Image]

[image: Smaller Image]

These are two images from the same website with same prefix and same format. The only difference is the size: the first is larger, while the second is smaller.

I downloaded both of the images to local folder and used Java to read them into BufferedImage objects. However, when I outputted the BufferedImages to local files, I found that the first image was almost red, while the second was normal(same as original). What's wrong with my code?

```
byte[] rawData = getRawBytesFromFile(imageFilePath); // some code to read raw bytes from image file
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData));
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(iis);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputImagePath, false);
ImageIO.write(img, "JPEG", fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

PS: I used GIMP to open the first image and detected that the Color Mode is 'sRGB', no alpha or other stuff.

Comment: emm, you choose a nice photos I liked your Taste:)
I don't know what's the problem with colors but try this

`BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/image"));`

Comment: actually, I've tried, but it failed...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java buffered image created with red mask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963685/java-buffered-image-created-with-red-mask)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is apparently a know bug, I saw several suggestions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963685/java-buffered-image-created-with-red-mask) is one) that suggest using `Toolkit#createImage` instead, which apparently ignores the color model.

I tested this and it seems to work fine.

```
public class TestImageIO01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Image in = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("C:\\hold\\test\\13652375852388.jpg");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(in)), "Yeah", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(in.getWidth(null), in.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = out.createGraphics();
            g2d.drawImage(in, 0, 0, null);
            g2d.dispose();

            ImageIO.write(out, "jpg", new File("C:\\hold\\test\\Test01.jpg"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

nb- I used the `JOptionPane` to verify the incoming image.  When using `ImageIO` it comes in with the red tinge, with `Toolkit` it looks fine.

**Updated**

And an [explantation](http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2009/04/odd-coloured-jpegs-in-java-with-imageio/)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code in netbeans and faced with your problem, then I changed the code as below that has no problem:

```
    public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


        byte[] rawData = getRawBytesFromFile(imageFilePath); // some code to read raw bytes from image file
//        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData));
//        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(iis);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputImagePath, false);
        fos.write(rawData);
//        ImageIO.write(img, "JPEG", fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }

    private static byte[] getRawBytesFromFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        byte[] image;
        File file = new File(path);
        image = new byte[(int)file.length()];

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(image);

        return image;
    }
}
```

Please check it and inform me of the result ;)

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when it cames to copying the image files, it definitely works. But, you know, I need to read the image file into BufferedImage object for further processing(like rotate or scale), so that is not the solution for this situation.

Comment: I changed the image format to PNG using photoshop and then I changed the png file to JPEG. with new jpg file everything is OK. [This is](http://postimg.org/image/b7y5hh9qf/) the new image.

Comment: Yeah, just like @MadProgrammer said, it is a bug of ImageIO that it fails to read some type of JPEG. When you use PS to resave it into a standard JPEG, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this solution might work just fine in the original poster's case.

```
String fileName = imageFilePath;
File inFile = new File(fileName);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inFile);
...
```

Best,