# BufferedImage Raster Data to BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage, raster

here's my code:

```
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getType());
WritableRaster raster = newImage.getRaster();
raster.setDataElements(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels);
newImage.setData(raster);
ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", new File("newimage.jpg"));
```

This code looks right to me and should do what I want. It gets the image's pixel data, then uses it to create a new image which should look exactly the same as the original image. However, the image that is saved has different colors than the original. Why?

Eventually, I'll need to manipulate the pixel bytes but for now, I don't know why it's giving me a different image.

Comment: Can you post a link to your (preferably small) original input and output image?

Answer (score 2):

This post may be of help [java buffered image created with red mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963685/java-buffered-image-created-with-red-mask)

It seems to be a common problem with ImageIO so its best to use Toolkit instead.

Comment: Could be related. Could also be completely unrelated. In any case I wouldn't really recommend using the Toolkit as a workaround. That specific bug is fixed in later JREs.