# Using ImageIO.read gives a modified image

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

I was doing some stuff with images in `JLabel`s, and I noticed that a few of the images (ones that contained black) that I was using were brighter in the label than they were supposed to be. The images were loaded through [`ImageIO#read(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-). Images loaded through `ImageIcon` constructors alone look normal.

Here's a small test that I threw together for this image:

[image: Test image]

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.setSize(320, 320);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

URL imageURL = new URL("https://wiki.factorio.com/images/Crude-oil.png");

frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(imageURL))));

frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageURL)));

frame.setVisible(true);
```

The result:

[image: Result]

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4881314) and it occurs when `ImageIO.read()` fails to find the proper color model of an image.

On the contrary, the constructor `ImageIcon(Url)` displays the image properly as it retrieves the image using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Url)`.

This bug can occur on other image extensions too. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12967094/2440339).

**EDIT**

Scroll down and compare the **Color Type** in the **PNG** section from the links below.

http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=https://wiki.factorio.com/images/Crude-oil.png

http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=http://www.sherv.net/cm/emoticons/hand-gestures/victory-fingers-black-smiley-emoticon.png

You will see that both the color types are different besides both images being PNGs. The problem with `ImageIO.read()` is that it can read **RGB with Alpha** properly but not **Grayscale with Alpha**.

I also found that `ImageIO.read().getType()` returns 0 = [*TYPE_CUSTOM*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_CUSTOM) for the first image and 6 = [*TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR) for the second. *TYPE_CUSTOM* is usually returned for images whose type is not recognized.

Comment: Thank you; interesting that both of your links (the bug and other answer) reference JPEGs, while mine is a PNG.

Comment: Sorry about that, I could not find any reference related to PNG but I have found something interesting now. Please check the edit.

Comment: Also interesting; I greatly appreciate the extra research. Afraid I can't upvote again, or I would.